# Access parent class vars from child class

Tags: python, class, object

Will this work ?
What are a better options ?

```
class Liketool():
  def __init__(self, parent: Instapy):
    self.parent = parent
    print('Liketool' + self.parent.my_name)

class Folllowtool():
  def __init__(self, parent: Instapy):
    self.parent = parent
    print('Folllowtool' + self.parent.my_name)

class Instapy(Liketool, Folllowtool):
  def __init__(self):
    self.my_name = 'moshe'
    super().__init__(self)
```

I don't like the use of `self.parent.my_name` can I somehow do it that `self.my_name` will see the Instapy vars ? when called from Folllowtool ?

WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE:

I have one session manager for social media operation.
I have like tool and follow tool that do specific operations.

I want to be able to get parent to know it's child Liketool to be able to access Instapy data.

EXAMPLE:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/super
[image]

ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION:
What do you think on that ?

```
class Liketool:
  def __init__(self, session: Instapy):
    self.session = session 
    print('Liketool' + self.session.my_name)

class Folllowtool:
  def __init__(self, session: Instapy):
    self.session = session 
    print('Folllowtool' + self.session.my_name)

class Instapy():
  def __init__(self):
    self.my_name= 'moshe'
    self.like = Liketool(self)
    self.follow = Folllowtool(self)
```

Comment: No, there's no built-in link from an object to the parent.

Comment: "Will this work ? " - paste it into any good IDE and it will show red lines, which means: no.

Comment: You could declare a property in Liketool that follows the `.parent` link.

Comment: `Liketool.__init__()` needs to call `super().__init__(parent)` so that `Folllowtool.__init__()` will be called.

Comment: Instapy inherits from Liketool. But Instapy shall be the parent of Liketool. I think you have a misunderstanding of inheritance.

Comment: @Barmar: just to get that right: that means I introduce a child class and for that reason I must change the one of the base classes? This definitely violates the OCP.

Comment: Okay, so the problem is likely an XY-problem. Please describe what you really want to achieve. Multiple inheritance is probably not what you want or need to solve your problem.

Comment: @ThomasWeller True, but that's how it works in Python. It's called ["cooperative multiple inheritance"](https://medium.com/swlh/cooperative-multiple-inheritance-paradigm-in-python-f048b7ecdb29)

Comment: @ThomasWeller You don't *have* to do it this way. The child class can call `Folllowtool.__init__(self, self)` directly.

Comment: This sounds like a situation where composition would work better than inheritance. i.e. the relationship should be "Tool HAS-A SessionManager" rather than "Tool IS-A SessionManager".

Comment: @slothrop I think you are right, what is the correct way of doing it ? is it like in ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION ?

Comment: Yes, that looks like it's the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend rethinking your problem. To me it looks like an XY-issue. You are trying to solve a problem for which you think multiple inheritance is the solution. Likely, it's not. I never needed to use multiple inheritance in 20 years of programming. There may be better solutions, but then we need to understand the underlying problem.

That said, what comes into my mind for a combination of multiple objects is this:

```py
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.somevalue = 5


class AnotherClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.something = 71
        self.somevalue = 842


class Combined:
    def __init__(self):
        self.combined_of = [SomeClass(), AnotherClass()]

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        for part in self.combined_of:
            try:
                return part.__getattribute__(name)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        raise AttributeError


c = Combined()
print(c.somevalue)
print(c.something)
```

`Combined` combines all properties of the listed classes in the order of their appearance in the list. `__getattr__()` is called, when an object does not have that property. The `for`-loop simply asks all parts if they have that property and returns the value of the first that has it.

Comment: Well that is not a good solution, SomeClass dont see Combined vars. also we inefficiency

Comment: Please also check the EXAMPLE I added, the example I gave will work

Comment: @Sisi: worrying about efficiency in Python is a bit strange. If I want efficient code, I use C# and if I want super-efficient code, I use C++.

Comment: @Sisi: In the animals example, I don't see code how the `Animal` class has all properties of `Dog`. The animal example looks like it could be achieved by a decorator pattern as well.

Comment: @Sisi: the social media tool infrastructure to me looks like you want a plugin architecture. That's *architecture* whereas I consider multiple inheritance as *detail design* which might not solve the problem.

Comment: I went with the "ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION"